# Non blocking read on files/getting file descriptors c++

Tags: c++, linux, ifstream, nonblocking, file-descriptor

I'm creating a program that get's information from different sources (named pipes and usb serial devices). I can successfully do that with a simple ifstream. But now I need to change it so the reads are non blocking, because the data is sparse and the order in which the sources provide data is unpredictable.
The location sources are unknown at startup but are found quickly and do not change afterwards. I use g++ to compile and the intended target is a raspberry pi 2 (with raspbian)

After some research i came across select() and poll(). The problem is they use file descriptors. I found very little on getting the file descriptors.
I found (fstream.rdbuf())->fd() but it doesn't compile (apparently it isn't supported anymore)

One possible solution I could think of is split the program into 2 parts:
one that searches for the files, and then uses bash to start program 2 with the correct files piped into it. (eg program2 <1 input1 <2 input 2 ...). At least I think this would work (I know you can redirect multiple outputs so I presume you can do redirect multiple inputs)
But it seems like a very bad solution (and I would need a way to be able to read from the file-descriptors as well (getting it in ifstream))

Another solution I could think of is to multi-thread. Each input gets their own thread and then it doesn't matter if the reads block. When a thread receives input, it would need to wake up the main thread and transfer the data.
This solution seems much better than the previous one but it's still seems unwieldy (is this the correct term?). I think this would be too complex for someone who has never multi-threaded before in c++, and this would probably cause hours of debugging to fix problems eg caused by multiple threads sending data simultaneously (unless c++ multi-threading is simpeler then I think it is).

So what other ways are there to solve this problem (or if there are no others, which of my 2 solutions would be recommended).

---

English is not my native language, so sorry for any mistakes.
This is also my first post on stackoverflow.
If you want to know how familiar I am with c++. I only learned c++ last semester on my university (though this is a personal project). And only wrote one project with about 25 classes (this was a group project, with 3 other people). But we learned quickly because we could apply much knowledge from other programming languages.

Comment: Have you ever written a program that uses `fork` with pipes? You have three choices: 1) Multiple processes. 2) Multiple threads. 3) I/O multiplexing.

Comment: if you are using c++14, you can use std::async. It is simple, portable and might meet your requirements. The important question is what do you really need to achieve? The right implementation of async IOs might be very different if you need a reactive UI with IOs in the background (std::async would be good enough), compared to a HPC solution where you need to use your hardware as efficiently as possible (a careful implementation of thread pools, buffering and producer/consumer pattern might be needed)

Comment: are people already using c++14? When we learned about c++11 in university, the professor warned us that most c++11 compilers are still experimental and had (rare but still) program breaking bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ streams do not expose underlying file descriptors (because file descriptors are OS-specific, and streams are universal).

You could use raw descriptors and write your own streams on top of it (not hard at all). However, you realize that async-io model requires certain skills? You are mentioning you are new to multithreading, have you ever worked with async io?

Comment: I have not worked with async-io, the only real multi-threading experience i have is with Java (some basic stuff, start threads  and safely stop threads, do some basic things with volatile, synchronized, wait and join) I'm pretty sure I have the enough experience with programming in general to try it, but it might take a bit before I get the hang of it.

Comment: @Sam, well, than just go for it. :)

Comment: I was going to try it with boost but I misunderstood it's basic async capabilities (it's more geared towards networking). And it turned out i over estimated the difficulty to read with raw descriptors. so I'm going with that.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a Boost library that deals with Asynchronous IO in a cross platform manner. it wraps linux *epoll* and windows *IO Completion Ports* in a C++ way.

[Casablanca](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) is a cross platform Microsoft's platform geared toward backend development. they went further and wrapped Boost.Asio with psuedo non blocking `fstream` objects. it works by splitting the work into asynchrounous tasks.

Considering that currently there is no better solution, I'd go with Casablanca.
Also, I'd make sure that the stream are not having any unusuall `locale` which usually really decrease reading performance.

ps. the multithreaded solution sounds owefull in regards to `fstream` performance.